# Laravel Autenticação por Rotas

Tags: php, laravel

Existe alguma forma no Laravel de adicionar permissões ou colocar um usuários em um grupo especifico na hora de fazer o login (me refiro a estrutura de Auth do proprio Laravel).

Exemplo, eu definir que somente um Grupo Admin tem acesso a Rota Produtos/Criar e que a rota Produtos/Listar pode ser vista tanto pelo grupo Admin como pelo Grupo Usuarios (e vice versa).

Comment: Tem sim, você pode criar um  Middleware especifico para determinados agrupamentos de rotas. Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware

Answer (score -1):

Você pode resolver isso com as policies:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization#creating-policies